# React App error PATCH http://localhost:4000/items/undefined

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, crud

I am getting this error trying to update a card for my application. Here's a look at the rails server log. The ID is coming back "nil". I can't figure out why. Here is the PATCH update block of code:

```
function handleEdit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(`/items/${item.id}`,{
   method: "PATCH",
   body: JSON.stringify({
    
    item: id,
    bottle: bottle,
    size: size,
    count: count,
   }),
   headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
   .then(res=>res.json())
   .then((updatedItem)=>setItem(updatedItem))
 }
```

Here are all the routes:

```
 resources :items, only: [:index,:show,:update]
 

 get '/me', to: 'couriers#show'
 get "/home", to: 'couriers#show'
 get '/courier', to: 'couriers#show'
 get '/items', to: 'items#index'
 get 'items/:id', to: 'items#update'

 get '/items/:id', to: 'items#show'
 patch '/items/:id', to: 'items#update'
 
 post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
 post '/signupform', to: 'couriers#create'

 delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Here is the error log:

```
Started PATCH "/items/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-08-01 19:27:47 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"item"=>nil, "bottle"=>"Glass", "size"=>"400", "count"=>"4", "id"=>"undefined"}
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/items_controller.rb:19:in `update'
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 1234)
```

Here is the code in the ItemsController:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authorize, except: :index

    def index
     items = Item.all
     render json: items, status: :ok
    end

    def show
        item=Item.find_by(id:session[:id])
    if  item
        render json: item
    else
        render json: {error: 'Not Found'}, status: :not_found
        end
    end

    def update
        item = Item.find_by(id:params[:id])
      if item
        item.update(item_params)
        render json: item
      else
        render json: { error: "Item not found" }, status: :not_found
      end
    end

    private

    def item_params
     params.permit(:id,:item,:bottle, :size, :count)
    end

end
```

If anyone has an idea or resolution, please share. I'm sure it's something I may be doing wrong, so anything helps.

Comment: Thanks dbugger, updated code as text.

Comment: `item: id`, should probably be  `item: item.id`

Comment: Tested that change too. Got this error: 
`Started PATCH "/items/undefined" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-08-02 16:46:36 -0400 Processing by ItemsController#update as / Parameters: {"bottle"=>"Metal", "size"=>"400", "count"=>"30", "id"=>"undefined", "item"=>{"bottle"=>"Metal", "size"=>"400", "count"=>"30"}} Item Load (0.5ms) SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]] ↳ app/controllers/items_controller.rb:19:in update Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Allocations: 690) 
`
@dbugger

Comment: pretty clear that you don't have `item` defined in that method -- so it can't pull an id

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure how React apps work, but should that `${items.id}` in the patch code be `${item.id}` (singular)?

Out of curiosity, where is the `item` (or `items`) var actually set? Again, I'm not familiar with React, but that's the source of the 'undefined' text being passed to the controller. Whatever is rendered in the `${ }` section is undefined. It is being turned into the literal text 'undefined' and that is being sent to your controller.

Comment: The value is pulled from the data when I fetch it in the App component. I then destructure it to the EditPickups component and attempt to use the data there.